# Ask when close tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to ask user, when close my page. I tried this scripts:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
    function confirmExit() {
        return "alert";
    }
</script>
```

.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var areYouReallySure = false;
  function areYouSure() {
    if(allowPrompt){
        if (!areYouReallySure && true) {
            areYouReallySure = true;
            var confMessage = "***************************************\n\n W A I T !!! \n\nBefore leaving our site, follow CodexWorld for getting regular updates on Programming and Web Development.\n\n\nCLICK THE *CANCEL* BUTTON RIGHT NOW\n\n***************************************";
            return confMessage;
        }
    } else {
        allowPrompt = true;
    }
  }

var allowPrompt = true;
window.onbeforeunload = areYouSure;
</script>
```

.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    return "You should keep this page open.";
  });
</script>
```

I read that in modern browsers scripts may not work. Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Wow that is annoying... Maaaybe don't annoy your users instead?

Comment: I agree. Not trying to be mean, but that tactic would drive me to never want to visit your site again. Consider a more subtle way to ask for subscriptions, like a sidebar or something that pops up in the bottom corner while the user is browsing.